# VSCode Extension API - retrieve workspace setting value of undefined

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, configuration

I am currently learning to develop vscode extension. In the extension development host, I add a workspace setting

```
"settings": {
        "test.display": {
            "editor.displayMe":true,
            "aaaa":true
        }
    }
```

Then in my extension.ts in the activate function, i have these 2 lines

```
    const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("test.display")
    const value = config.get("editor.displayMe");
    const value1 = config.get("aaaa");
```

Strangely, the value is actually undefined, instead of the expected value of true, but value1 is true, which is as expected.
Does that mean I cannot have a dot as in the "editor.displayMe"?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.
According to docs "Dots in the section-identifier are interpreted as child-access..", hence my settings should be rewritten as

```
"settings": {
        "test.display": {
            "editor{
               displayMe":true
            }
            "aaaa":true
        }
```